# How to install a printer without Internet connection

Tags: drivers, printing

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS, into a HP ProBook 4440s laptop, and I need to install the drivers of a printer (Epson, scanner & printer, all in one).

The problem is... Where the printer and the laptop are, there is not an Internet connection (it is far, far away, out of my city, in a a farm).

Can Ubuntu works with that printer?

I'm thinking about something like a generic printer driver, included into Ubuntu installation, which be useful to this... Maybe?

Or...

Does I need, yes or yes, an Internet connection to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

> Can Ubuntu works with that printer?

Probably or at least the printer part.

> Does I need, yes or yes, an Internet connection to perform this?

Yes, but not really needed on that laptop itself. You can download it all onto your current system and install it when you are there.

You can also install a ssh server onto that machine and copy and install it remotely.

[This does largely depends on the support for this printer](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supAdvice.jsp?noteoid=162111&type=highlights). Download the files you need form the link.